# In React component with conditionals (for filtering purpose), where to place Spinner?

Tags: reactjs, spinner, jsx

I am using Giphy API and have a working app that searches gifs. I have conditionals in my SearchResults Component so that user can filter the searched results (ex. Rated G, Rated PG, etc.). But each gif takes different amount of time to render, and I would love to add one spinner (created a Spinner component + gif) or spinners for each item for better UI/UX. Because my code has conditionals, I am confused as to how and where to place my spinner...
Would welcome any help or suggestions!

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import SearchCategories from './SearchCategories';
import SearchCard from './SearchCard';
// import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import { getFilteredByRating, getSortedByDate } from '../../utils/filters';

const SearchResult = ({
  gifs,
  searchMessage,
  ratingType,
  isDataSorting,
  onSortByDate,
  onSortByRating,
  onClearFilter,
}) => {
  const renderedGifs = gifs.slice();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h3 className="searchMessage text-center mb-4">{searchMessage}</h3>
      <SearchCategories
        onSortByDate={onSortByDate}
        onSortByRating={onSortByRating}
        onClearFilter={onClearFilter}
      />
      <br />

      {
        // if (gifs === undefined || !gifs.length) {
        //   return <Spinner />
        // } else {
        //   // the code below - the gif results
        // }
      }

      <div className="row justify-content-between">
        {(isDataSorting &&
          getSortedByDate(renderedGifs).map(gif => (
            <div className="col-md-3">
              <div className="m-2 card bg-transparent" key={gif.id}>
                <SearchCard gif={gif} />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))) ||
          (ratingType &&
            (getFilteredByRating(ratingType, renderedGifs).length !== 0 ? (
              getFilteredByRating(ratingType, renderedGifs).map(gif => (
                <div className="col-md-3">
                  <div className="m-2 card bg-transparent" key={gif.id}>
                    <SearchCard gif={gif} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <p className="searchNotFound">
                Oops! None of the search results match this rating.
              </p>
            ))) ||
          gifs.map(gif => (
            // col-3  col-lg-3
            <div className="col-md-3">
              <div className="m-2 card bg-transparent" key={gif.id}>
                <SearchCard gif={gif} />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SearchResult;
```

Comment: Perhaps extract individual gifs/images/element into a small functional component that initializes with a loading state true, and attach an `onLoad` event handler to the image asset element that updates local state. Display a spinner while loading is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look at your logic at all, but the syntax looked funny. See if this works... If not I'll delete this!

````
    //...

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h3 className="searchMessage text-center mb-4">{searchMessage}</h3>
        <SearchCategories
          onSortByDate={onSortByDate}
          onSortByRating={onSortByRating}
          onClearFilter={onClearFilter}
        />
        <br />

        {/* look here */}

        {gifs === undefined || !gifs.length ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <div className="row justify-content-between">
            {(isDataSorting &&
              getSortedByDate(renderedGifs).map(gif => (
                <div className="col-md-3">
                  <div className="m-2 card bg-transparent" key={gif.id}>
                    <SearchCard gif={gif} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))) ||
              (ratingType &&
                (getFilteredByRating(ratingType, renderedGifs).length !== 0 ? (
                  getFilteredByRating(ratingType, renderedGifs).map(gif => (
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                      <div className="m-2 card bg-transparent" key={gif.id}>
                        <SearchCard gif={gif} />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <p className="searchNotFound">
                    Oops! None of the search results match this rating.
                  </p>
                ))) ||
              gifs.map(gif => (
                // col-3  col-lg-3
                <div className="col-md-3">
                  <div className="m-2 card bg-transparent" key={gif.id}>
                    <SearchCard gif={gif} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );

    //...
    ```
````